# Kubernetes - delete all the pods from the node before reboot or shutdown using kubenetes API

Tags: bash, kubernetes

I need a bash script to delete only pods on specific node before shutdown or reboot using Kubernetes API.

Comment: Whats the question?

Comment: The question is how can I apply some filters for all the namespaces, than for each namespace get all pods and only delete some of them, based on filters, like in the second example. Which is not working.

Comment: Great. Thanks for clarifying the question. I see your question got answered as well! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that works for what I'm trying to achieve:

```
for each in $(curl -XGET https://URL/api/v1/namespaces  | jq -r '.items[].metadata.name'); 
  do arr=($(curl -XGET https://URL/api/v1/namespaces/$each/pods  | jq --arg node `hostname` -r '.items[] | select(.spec.nodeName == $node) | .metadata.name')); 
  for i in  ${arr[@]}; 
    do curl -XDELETE https://URL/api/v1/namespaces/$each/pods/$i ;
  done 
done
```

This is a script present on each Worker node and it's executed before each reboot or shutdown and deletes all the pods from all namespaces that are present on that node only. Before this, there is another command that marks the node as "unschedulable". If anyone is interested in this, I can post the complete solution

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to remove all pods from a particular node **and** stop new pods from being scheduled on that node, then [kubectl drain](http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_drain/) is what you probably want: It stops sending pods to the node and kills any existing ones.

It's as simple as invoking

```
kubectl drain NODE
```

and comes with a few extra switches to tweak the behavior (such as defining a graceful termination period).

Comment: I know about `drain` command in `kubectl`. In this case I want to execute the command from inside the nodes that are rebooting or shutting down without having to configure the `kubectl` on each one.  Anyway, looks like `kubectl` was integrated in `hyperkube` in the latest versions  and can be configured as a systemd service  and execute a `kubectl drain $hostname` before shutdown.

Comment: @Camil glad to hear it worked for you. Though it's not perfectly clear to me why you'd need kubectl running as a systemd service: kubectl is just a client to the Kubernetes master API server, so you should be able to install any compatible binary on your machine and use it to talk to the master. Is this something hyperkube specific (which I have zero experience with)?

Comment: I'm using `kube-aws` from CoreOS to deploy kubernetes on AWS. To be able to upgrade the cluster, I have to do a rolling update on each node. So, each node will be terminated and replaced by a new one. In this case I prefer to terminate all the pods present on that node and reschedule to another one before node shutdown and I want this to be automated. Hyperkube is an all-in-one binary for the Kubernetes server components.

Comment: If the node's ready status = Unknown (ability to talk to worker node lost) (from OOM of trying to schedule to much, kubelet/docker crash and not auto recovering, or network gltich)
then drain (which normally cordons and drains), will only be able to cordon as that requires talking to etcd, and it won't be able to drain as that requires talking to the node - which it can't do. IMO Camil's solution is better for that reason. 
(Ready Unknown is a common reason to need to Reboot/Shutdown.)